# Use poisson Random Timer to calculate think time in jmeter for every request

Tags: timer, jmeter, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-5.0

How to use the Poisson random timer in JMeter to calculate the think-time for every request in JMeter ?

Is it advisable to use the Poisson random timer in every request level ?

Is it possible to calculate the think-time for every request?

Comment: Have you read https://perfmatrix.blogspot.com/2017/01/apache-jmeter-poisson-random-timer.html ? If so, can you provide more details about what is not working for you as expected? What you mean by "calculate the think-time"?

Comment: Usual I will be calculating " Think-time" with average response time and the total number of user and with Total transaction (TPS).
These are my following functionalities that need to loaded test,
 Login
User Registration
(Need to fill the form and it consists of more than 20 fields)
Think time will not be the same for login and user registration.
And I asked to pass more realistic think for login and user registration.
How can I calculate think-time for a request? Is there any method to calculate think-time for request. @leberknect

Comment: Not sure if that can be done, sorry :/ ("not sure" as in "possible! I dont know jmeter so well"). Maybe jMeter is not really the best tool for your use-case? Its primarily used for load-testing. If you want to mimic realistic user behavior and the load is not-so-important, i would recommend using more e2e-faced tool like https://www.protractortest.org/#/ which gives you total freedom regarding pausing and stuff.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? did it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you put different Timers **under** different Samplers (e.g. HTTP request), then for each request the specific definiton will be applied as you requested. See more about [Execution order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)

In general choosing appropriate/more accurate think time for different requests is good choice when relevant